# How to call Dictionary<K, V>.TryGetValue() where K : Predicate<T>, V : enum

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, predicate, trygetvalue

I have `Dictionary<Predicate<double>, SomeEnum>`:

```
var dic = new Dictionary<Predicate<double>, SomeEnum>
{
    { (d) => d < 10, SomeEnum.Foo },
    { (d) => d > 90, SomeEnum.Bar }
};
```

I want to call `TryGetValue(K, out V)` against it like this:

```
dic.TryGetValue(99)
```

and receive

```
SomeStruct.Bar
```

But first param for `TryGetValue()` is `Predicate<T>`, not just `T`. How can I do what I want?

I found only a dirty workaround:

```
var kpv = dic.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Key(99));
if (kpv.Key != null)
    var result = kpv.Value;
```

Are there other ways?

**Or how to implement my idea properly?** - declare a key not as a constant but like a segment.

Comment: This is not how to use a hashtable.

Comment: @leppie: Agree. In my case it's just a `List<KeyValuePair<T,V>>` (I can't use 4.0 and `List<Tuple<T,V>>`) –

Comment: This is not how to use lambdas.

Comment: @Henk: Really? Where exactly?

Comment: Here: `{ { (d) => d < 10, SomeStruct.Foo },`

Comment: @Henk: How to use collection initializer properly where collection element is `Predicate<T>`?

Comment: @Henk: Elucidate (or delete the comment), please

Comment: @abatishchev - my guess is that it needs to be cast to a `Predicate<T>` since C# won't infer the type.

Comment: @codekaizen: As far as operators `<`,`>` returns `bool`, C# infers the return type correctly

Comment: abatishchev, Matt Brunell makes my argument very well.

Comment: @Henk: He uses the same lambda declaration. Doesn't he?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of things wrong here:

`Predicate<double>` is not an appropriate type to use as a `TKey`.  The key for a dictionary is supposed to *identify* a value, not calculate a value.

This wouldn't make any sense using lambdas either.  Because they are anonymous, you wouldn't get any equivalence, and won't be able use a dictionary.

See this code sample for an illustration:

```
Predicate<double> fn_1 = d => d == 34.0d;
Predicate<double> fn_2 = d => d == 34.0d;

// Note: There are not equal
if (fn_1 == fn_2)
    Console.WriteLine("These are Equal?");
```

If anything, you could use a list of delegates and execute each one to find the ones that match, but at that point you must expect multiple results.  If you only want to get a single result, then you have to consider which *order* the predicates are stored within your list.

Don't misuse `KeyValuePair` as a hack for not having `Tuple<T1,T2>`.  It would be fairly easy to create a class that has both a Predicate and a SomeStruct.  Look:

```
public class MySegment
{   
     public Predicate<double> Predicate {get;set;}
     public SomeStruct Result {get;set;}
}
```

To go through a sequence of predicates, and find the matching ones would look like this:

```
...
List<MySegment> list = new List<MySegment>();
...
list.Add(new MySegment { Predicate = d => d < 10, Result = SomeStruct.Foo });
list.Add(new MySegment { Predicate = d => d > 90, Result = SomeStruct.Bar });

...

public IEnumerable<SomeStruct> GetResults(double input)
{ 
    foreach (var item in list)
        if (item.Predicate(input))
             yield return item.Result;
}
```

Comment: +1, for a clear description of the issues, though from a style standpoint I'd make GetResults `return from i in list where i.Predicate(input) select i.Result;`. Just a matter of preference, though.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Only one note - predicates I have a unique (because describes segments [0;30], [70,100]) that's why I decided to use Dictionary or KVP.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior: `list.Where(item => item.Predicate(input))` also works to me properly

Answer (score 2):

If your list of predicates is not too long, you can just add them to a `List<KeyValuePair<Predicate<T>, V>>` and then perform a LINQ query:

```
var lt10 = new KeyValuePair<Predicate<Double>, SomeStruct>(d => d < 10, SomeStruct.Foo);
var gt90 = new KeyValuePair<Predicate<Double>, SomeStruct>(d => d > 90, SomeStruct.Bar);
var predicates = new List<KeyValuePair<Predicate<Double>, SomeStruct>>() { lt10, gt90 };

var result = predicates.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Key(99));
```

You're better off using `SomeStruct?` instead of `SomeStruct`, furthermore, since then `FirstOrDefault` will give an unambiguous result if it doesn't match any.

If your list is very long, you will want to consider some kind of data structure which permits queries on a range, like an [Interval Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree).

Comment: Looks like that I described the same approach in my workaround, right?

Comment: Yes, but by switching to `List` you will be using the correct data structure, giving you more performance. A `Dictionary` is just not a good fit here. Using a `List` and iterating through it with `FirstOrDefault` is a good, practical approach, and is even optimal for small numbers of items.

Comment: @Matt Brunell - Now it does, as well as giving correct answers.

Answer (score 2):

This cannot be done using a Dictionary, because it relies on hash values to quickly determine where to look for a particular key.

As you've discovered, you can invoke the predicates directly, but that will require O(n) functions to be called, which is no better than using a List, or even a big if/then/else statement.

If your collection of potential predicates is too long for this to be an option, you'll need to create your own data structure to satisfy your purposes. If you're only planning to define values based on integer ranges, this shouldn't be difficult, but it could get out of hand if your predicates get more complex.

On a side note, the F# language, which has built-in support for this sort of definition using [Match Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233242.aspx). I don't know how it goes about compiling the branches, but I assume it's fairly smart about it.

**Edit**

Here's an example of using a Match Expression in F# for something like this:

```
// Define the "choose" function
let choose value = 
    match value with
    | v when v < 10 -> 1
    | v when v > 90 -> 2
    | _ -> 0

// Test the "choose" function
let choice1 = choose 5
let choice2 = choose 15
let choice3 = choose 95
```

The code above yields the following values:

```
choice1 = 1 
choice2 = 0 
choice3 = 2
```

I've never actually worked with F# before, so you'll have to look around for how to use a function from F# in a C# program.

Comment: It seems that F# is really what I need. Thanks for pointing me to it!

Comment: I even don't imagine how should it look in F# and how to answer a question regarding it. Could you please assist me? How to describe in F# notation the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to loop through your criteria and run each Predicate against the input to see if it matches.  I don't see any reason to use a Dictionary here.

Comment: I have `Dictionary<K,V>` just because it's easier to write it then `List<KeyValuePair<K,V>>` as I mentioned already in the first comment to the post.