# Using a List as a condition for LINQ to SQL query

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql

I have a LINQ to SQL query that goes like this:

```
String NameCondition = "Test";
String EmailCondition = "test@test.com";

IQueryable<User> Users = Repository.Where(x => x.Name.Equals(NameCondition) && x.Email.Equals(EmailCondition));
```

But now I have a list of conditions where I would like to pull Users from if they match any of them (like an OR statement in SQL). So I have a list of dictionaries, and each dictionary is a condition with a name and email:

```
List<Dictionary<String, String>> Conditions;
```

How can I perform a LINQ to SQL query using those conditions?

Comment: Why do you have a list of dictionaries? It sounds like you're saying that each dictionary only contains one entry. Is that the case?

Answer (score 0):

Use `PredicateBuilder` by Josef Albahari

http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx

Here is a sample usage.

```
IQueryable<Product> SearchProducts (params string[] keywords)
{
  var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<Product>();

  foreach (string keyword in keywords)
  {
    string temp = keyword;
    predicate = predicate.Or (p => p.Description.Contains (temp));
  }
  return dataContext.Products.Where (predicate);
}
```

Comment: why the edit Daniel.?? i thought the usage example supported the link well

Comment: @jim It's joyful to use the privileges :-)

Comment: ab(use) in my case probably :-)

Comment: Something strange is going on. I don't remember if the example was in the version I edited, however I definitely did not remove it. I only altered the formatting of the link. It was originally backtick-quoted, which caused the link not to work.

Comment: I think this is a result of the '5-minute window' feature of SO: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9090/is-there-an-editing-grace-period-on-answers-after-they-have-been-posted

Answer (score 0):

Instead of dictionary use `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>` in .NET 3.5 and `List<Tuple<string, string>>` in .NET 4.0.

See some kind similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4307535/how-to-call-dictionaryk-v-trygetvalue-where-k-predicatet-v-enum)